VIM filetype detection not working for new file
I'm deploying a new server and modifying MySQL configs, and vim is not detecting file type on a newly created file.  The config files I have are:
/etc/my.cnf <-- preinstalled, was working, no longer working after editing
/etc/01-mysqld.cnf <-- I created this file, not working
/etc/50-galera.cnf <-- preinstalled, working
/etc/51-galera-4-wsrep-provider.cnf <-- preinstalled, working

I have checked /usr/share/vim/vim91/filetype.vim and it appears that nothing is configured for *.cnf files, and I can't tell what match is applying the rule.  The value shown when using :set ft are conf for the working ones, and empty string for the non-working ones.
How do I get highlighting back without setting the type every time I open a file?  Is there a way to apply a global generic rule that applies to all *.cnf and *.conf files if not already shown in filetype.vim?

It may be a modeline in the existing files that is setting the filetype.

I didn't see anything explicitly setting a type.  I added a # comment above [mysqld] and that brought higlighting back (only having comments below didn't work).  Anyways, thanks for pointing me in the right direction
